# Isn't the title of the book supposed to be italicized in apa?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, apacite

When I compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{apacite}


\begin{document}
\nocite{atkins2014atkins}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{lib}
\end{document}
```

With the following .bib:

```
@INCOLLECTION{atkins2014atkins,
  title={Elements Of Physical Chemistry, Fifth edition},
  chapter={Chemical equilibrium:
equilibria in solution},
  author={Atkins, Peter and de Paula, Julio},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Oxford university press},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {172-192}
}
```

The title of the book is not italicized, shouldn't it be according to the apa style?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the question in the title of your query: That would be a "Yes".

The reason you are not getting this outcome is that you are not using the `@incollection` entry type correctly.

You need to fix the following issues:

- change `title` to `booktitle`
- change `chapter` to `title`
- move the edition information into its own field called `edition`
- change `howpublished` to `pages`
- fix the spelling in the `publisher` field

[image]

Note that the book title -- but not the chapter title -- is rendered in italics.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{lib.bib}
@incollection{atkins2009,
  author   = {Atkins, Peter and de Paula, Julio},
  title    = {Chemical equilibrium: Equilibria in solution},
  pages    = {172--192},
  booktitle= {Elements of Physical Chemistry},
  year     = {2009},
  edition  = {5},
  publisher= {Oxford University Press},
}
\end{filecontents}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{lib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ... And then enclose the booktitle in curly braces so its capitalization survives BibTeX's rampant lowercasization.

Comment: @StephanKolassa - It’s not BibTeX *per se*, but the bibliography style in use, that determines whether sentence style or title style is to be employed. The `apacite` bib style is known to be particularly aggressive in enforcing sentence style — even in `booktitle` fields.